# Ubuntu 18.04.3: Set the environment for bash script that runs through Gnome Startup Application

Tags: 18.04, bash, gnome, environment-variables, startup-applications

On Ubuntu 18.04.3 GUI, I am using GNOME Startup Application to start my bashscript because `@reboot` for `cron` doesn't work for me ([cron - crontab's @reboot only works for root? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root)).

How can I set (and view existing) the environment for GNOME Startup Application GUI?

---

## EDIT

Relevant image and data:

[image: Startup]

[image]

```bsh
$ ls ~/.config/autostart/
alarm-clock-applet.desktop       nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop
albert.desktop@                  org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
bash.desktop                     psensor.desktop
blueman.desktop                  remmina-applet.desktop
code.desktop                     safeeyes.desktop@
google-chrome.desktop            shutter.desktop
ignore-lid-switch-tweak.desktop  snap-userd-autostart.desktop
keepassxc.desktop                urserver.desktop
```

```bsh
cat ~/.config/autostart/bash.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/bin/bash /home/nikhil/opt/bin/Startup
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=MyStartupApplications
Name=MyStartupApplications
Comment[en_US]=MyStartup Applications
Comment=MyStartup Applications
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What exactly do you want to know? Edit the title of the question to reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

System-wide startup applications are stored as `.desktop` files in the `/etc/xdg/autostart/` directory. If you (or an application) have manually added a startup application only for the current user, then it would be found in your `~/.config/autostart/` directory. You can edit the `.desktop` files with a text-editor of your choice.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question: `MyStartupApplication` is supposed to run `/bin/bash /home/nikhil/opt/bin/Startup`. But there is no relevant desktop file in the path as you mentioned!

Comment: The actual executable can be anywhere, what I meant that the `.desktop` files which helps launching the application at startup should be found in `~/.config/autostart/`. Did you check the *contents* of those files in `~/.config/autostart/`? What about the `bash.desktop` file in particular (i.e. what does `cat ~/.config/autostart/bash.desktop` say)?

Comment: Yes `bash.desktop` is about by bashscript (please see the EDIT in the question at the end). How can I set the environment here?

Comment: Which environment? What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The bashscript `Startup` uses some functions defined in `~/.bashrc`. But my `~/.bashrc` checks if it is run interactively or not. By environment I meant functions defined inside my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Still not completely clear to me, perhaps explicit examples would be helpful. Why not modify the script itself?